# Where do I see my rejected suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

According to my suggested-edit stats, I have had one suggestion rejected.

Where can I see that rejected edit?

I looked in my user "Activity" tab and didn't see it. I can filter by "suggestions" but that just shows the suggestions and not what happened to them. Neither "reviews" or "revisions" list any rejections.

(Note: I don't really care about *this* particular rejected edit. I just want to know, *in general*, where I can see these.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the moment, you've basically got to click through every suggested edit you have to find out whether it was rejected or accepted. Yes, you have to do that.

What I'd love to see is this, which would show the "approved" or "rejected" right in your profile:

[image]

But no, they haven't fixed this yet, and given the number of times me and others have asked they won't seem to do this in the near future:

> #### [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

Comment: Well that's a bummer. Thanks.

Comment: The only way I could see is that a moderator might have the ability to look it up for you? Maybe they can see more in-depth stats. But I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to view information like this that the user interface doesn't expose.

Here is one [query to find a user's rejected edits](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/45755/my-rejected-edits) on SuperUser.