# Notify a rejected or accepted edit

Tags: feature-request, tags, editing

I would like to propose to somehow **notify a rejected edit**.

Meanwhile the accepted edit give a +2 and it is somehow notified in the Recent Inbox Messages, the rejected one is difficult to find [[1](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5212/where-do-i-see-my-rejected-suggested-edits/5213#5213),[2](https://meta.superuser.com/a/7992/257269)] and have to be searched for.

If it happens that someone is not interested to see each moment the score going up, it is possible that he/she forgets about that edit and miss even the comment that sometimes are given with the rejection.

Comment: A reasonable enough feature request. I'm sure they'll get to this in 6-8 weeks ;-)

Comment: SE duplicate: [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624)

Comment: I was so desperate the other day I tried using a [StackExchange Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/45755/my-rejected-edits) until I found out about it being displayed under All Actions.

Answer (score 7):

You stated:

> It is possible that he/she forgets about that edit and miss even the comment that sometimes are given with the rejection.

Unlikely, as the **next** time they submit an edit they will see a **warning** about the last reject:

> Kevin implemented this as described below. One rejected edit will
>   produce the following warning:
>
> [image: Attention! Your last edit was rejected]
>
> That links back to the last edit that was rejected. If the editor
>   *never* gets any edits approved, they'll see this every time they go to edit, until they're banned. If *some* are approved but many are
>   rejected (see details below), they'll get a more noticeable warning:
>
> [image: Warning! Some of your previous edits were rejected]
>
> ...Which links to /users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions.
>   <strike>We're not *currently* indicating whether these have been
>   approved or rejected on that page.</strike> **UPDATE (December 10,
>   2014):** [We now show suggested edit outcomes on that page (pending,
>   approved, or
>   rejected)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history).
>
> Finally, there's an in-between warning that'll appear for folks who
>   get *most* of their edits approved but have a few declines (see below
>   for details):
>
> [image: Attention! Some of your previous edits were rejected]
>
> Again, this links to the viewer's suggested edit history, and should
>   allow conscientious editors to find past edits even when their most
>   recent edit was approved.

Source [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

Comment: I've not seen/noticed any warning. BTW and even for this, I'm proposing to put it in the "Recent Inbox Message", eventually even as an option for the users.  Moreover when it is past some amount of time, it's time consuming to search for rejected edit [under suggestions](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5212/where-do-i-see-my-rejected-suggested-edits/5213#5213). Even in this link the author agree with Feature request #2 that doesn't exclude to put it in the "Recent Inbox Message" too. I mean I know as I did --> I learn else I Forget and waste time (mine and moderator too).

Comment: @Hastur You won't see the warning as you have over 2K on [su] so your edits don't need approval.

Comment: But for tags wiki and excerpts I need approval... (and I noticed it exactly with these). Did I _post tag_ with tags tag too? ( I didn't resist to the words joke forgive me :-) )

Comment: @Hastur Then it's a bug if your are not seeing the warnings for tag edit ;)

Comment: If you want to turn this into a bug report.  This question should be migrated to [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Ramhound I cannot be sure, else I just turned it in bug.  I'm usually really tired when I relax with SU. I've made excerpt and wiki tag at the same time to make them as uniform as it was possible... even for this (maybe at least for tags) i think it is better to have a notification in the "Recent Inbox Message"

Comment: There is no harm done if you choose to report this bug.  It either is intended behavior or a bug either way, the site I suggested would get you the best answer ( from a SE developer )